# Is there an proverb or saying in English for '叶公好龙'?

Tags: translation

I do think that '叶公好龙’ is very image, and very vividly for describing someone who is faking passion, and is a very common word, are there any English one for '叶公好龙'?

Comment: 叶公好龙 is not a common proverb, I have never heard of it

Comment: user recommendation: search web for more 成语 containing names of historical figures: results include 含有历史人物的姓或名的成语 https://www.wenkuxiazai.com/doc/22f63a7501f69e31433294f3-4.html  which includes 叶公

Answer (score 1):

> 葉公好龍 http://www.epochtimes.com/b5/3/11/2/n404356.htm
>
> *從這個故事演變的成語“葉公好龍”常用來比喻人說一套，做一套，口是心非*

In English, it is similar to " talk the talk, but not walk the walk' meaning someone's words doesn't match his action' (說一套，做一套)

Comment: Actually, 'talk the talk, walk the walk' means 说到做到. (說一套，做一套)  is talk the talk, but not walk the walk.

Comment: Yes, answer edited

Answer (score 0):

这很难说。 我个人认为这并不意味着假装有激情，更像是害怕面对现实, 生活在梦境中。

他喜欢龙的形象，但现实中的龙，一条真正的龙，把他吓死了。

Perhaps we should be afraid of dragons， but please don't kill them!

Maybe a saying from that old Greek slave Æsop:

It is easy to be brave from a safe distance.